# How to fix dataTables search box and paging position issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have 2 problem with my dataTables where;

1. Why my "search" and "paging" is not located right position?  Why it be at the middle? Should be at blue box.

[image]

2. Why there is no "plus" symbol when the pixel change to Mobile view.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<table id="manageadmin" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Username</th>
            <th class="text-center">Email</th>
            <th class="text-center">Division/Unit</th>
            <th class="text-center">Workgroup</th>
            <th class="text-center">Status Account</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#manageadmin').DataTable( {
        ajax: { 
            url: 'assets/data/dummy.json',
            crossDomain : true,
            type : "GET",
            cache : false,
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataSrc : "data"
        },
        columns: [
            { data : "fullname", "className": "text-center" },
            { data : "username", "className": "text-center" },
            { data : "email", "className": "text-center" },
            { data : "divunit", "className": "text-center" },
            { data : "workgroup", "className": "text-center" },          

        ],
    });
});
```

**Import JS**

```
<script src="src/plugins/jQuery-3.2.1/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/plugins/bootstrap-4.0.0/dist/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/plugins/bootstrap-4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/plugins/datatables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<script src="src/plugins/datatables/media/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<script src="src/plugins/datatables/media/js/responsive.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<script src="src/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```

Comment: some other css is overriding Datatable css. Inspect and check Search element css

Comment: you are great, I forgot to include datatables css.